# How to store math equation from word to sql database and also retrieve from sql table and generate pdf of that?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, math, wmf

I am working on Educational Software and there is need to save maths equation from word file to sql database. There are different type of content document like maths,physics and chemistry. I want to save those word documents content(which are in specific provide in table format) in sql table.

I have make some flow in my winforms application like copy content from word and get data from clipboard then i am trying to save that equation in Bitmap file or image file or byte but not working that flow.

```
        IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        data.GetData(DataFormats.MetafilePict);

        Stream memoryStream = (Stream)data.GetData(DataFormats.MetafilePict);
        byte[] byt1 = ReadFully(memoryStream);
        using (var imageFile = new FileStream("d:/tempimg1.bmp", FileMode.Create))
        {
            imageFile.Write(byt1,0, byt1.Length);
            imageFile.Flush();
            imageFile.Close();
        }
```

On above snippet i am trying to get Math equation from clipboard and trying to convert that equation to bitmap image but its not convert properly and when i am open that image is not provide preview.
I need guideline do achieve that. But How ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you ask someone here do your project:)

Comment: I have make some flow in my winforms application like copy content from word and get data from clipboard then i am trying to save that equation in Bitmap file or image file or byte but not working that flow.

I need guideline do achieve that. But How ?

Comment: guys i am not asking to develop my project to someone else i need flow if any one have idea of this kind of things. :)

Comment: honestly your question is not clear,if you want people answer you have to put some code in your question and say exactly which part of your code has problem.

Comment: Yes, i know that but i am also confuse to achieve that. I have try to put some code here.

Comment: Sticking to Word seems like a bad idea to me.  LaTeX is the standard for math typesetting; I think you'd be better off with that.  You're always free to simply store CLOBs in your database.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. You mention `SQL`, but your problem seems strictly getting an object from the clipboard and converting that object to an image. Perhaps a better title is `Convert Word object to image` or `Get Word object from clipboard and convert to image`

Comment: Possible links that might help: https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+convert+word+equation+image&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Calling this code:

```
    int equationIndex = 2;
    OMath om = wordApplication.ActiveDocument.OMaths[equationIndex];
    om.Range.Select();
    wordApplication.Selection.CopyAsPicture();
    String html = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Html) as String;
```

Copies the specified equation to the clipboard as `HTML` with some preamble meta data at the top. Down at the bottom of the `html` is this:

```
<img width=333 height=62
src="file:///C:\Users\...username...\AppData\Local\Temp\msohtmlclip1\01\clip_image002.png"
v:shapes="_x0000_i1025">
```

So then you can parse the `html` and then read the file like any other `png` image.